# how find most readers reach post laravel?

Tags: laravel, web, laravel-5

I hope to develop magazine type web site with admin dashboard with laravel 5.5 and I want to find most readers reach post in my website. are they any special way to do it with laravel  please hep me?

Comment: **Yes** there are many ways to do this

Comment: I hope you add reader count some where in your database.